# XStream Single Element Array JSON

Tags: arrays, json, xstream

I'm generating some JSON with XStream for an object that contains an ArrayList. I have the @XStreamImplicit annotation set for the specific field. When I have 2 elements in the array it converts to JSON properly...

```
"cap": [
            "switch",
            "switch2"
       ]
```

However if there is only one element in the array I get this...

```
"cap": "switch"
```

Therefore it's not showing up as an array (even though there is only one element in it). This makes it a challenge to deserialize it on the other end (which I do not have control of). What I want it to do is the following...

```
"cap": [
            "switch"
       ]
```

I'm assuming this is some sort of automatic assumption made for efficiency sake in the library. Either in XStream or Jettison. However is there a way to force the array setting here?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? If yes, can you share the work-around?

Comment: @xybrek Unfortunately I was not able to resolve this. I ended up having to hack in a check for this and then manually generate the JSON myself. I'm in the process of converting my calls to xstream over to JAXB (2.3.0). This was mainly to handle JPA entity classes that need to be serialized and deserialized (xstream doesn't handle bi-directional relationships well). But it may also help here. I just haven't gotten that far yet.  It may seem daunting to make that conversion but it honestly was not very difficult or time consuming and it works very well. Might be worth a look for you.